# How can I disable pvs-studio specific warnings for a cmake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, pvs-studio

I want to completely disable certain diagnostics without changing the source code.
How do I do that?

I looked through the documentation, but it's pretty confusing. I see three options such as: use cfg files (cfg or pvsconfig) with two different formats or a json file without mentioning its format.

My development environment is linux, vscode, cmake.
Part of my CMakeList.txt:

```
pvs_studio_add_target(TARGET parser.analyze ALL
                    CONFIG ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/rules.pvsconfig
                    OUTPUT
                    HIDE_HELP
                    FORMAT errorfile-verbose
                    ANALYZE ${PROJECT_NAME}
                    MODE GA:1,2
                    )
```

where rules.pvsconfig:

```
//-V::730
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the `*.pvsconfig` file with comments about turning off diagnostic rules, you can put it into `pvs_studio_add_target` through the `ARGS` option:

```
pvs_studio_add_target(TARGET parser.analyze ALL
                      ARGS --rules-config "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/rules.pvsconfig"
                      OUTPUT
                      HIDE_HELP
                      FORMAT errorfile-verbose
                      ANALYZE ${PROJECT_NAME}
                      MODE GA:1,2
)
```

Note that the `CONFIG` option defines a `*.cfg` file which is a slightly different entity. You can read more about that [here](https://pvs-studio.com/en/docs/manual/6615/#cfg).